# What tables are updated when a new product return is made?

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I need to know because when a customer is requesting a product return on the frontend there are no notification that shows up and let our employee know that a new product return has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Magento 1.x Enterprise Edition? If so, you can configure email notifications when an RMA has been initiated.

1. On the Admin menu, select `System > Configuration`.
2. If applicable, set `Current Configuration Scope` to the website where the configuration applies.
3. In the panel on the left, under `Sales`, select `Sales Emails`.
4. Click to expand the `RMA` section, and complete the fields as needed.

**Official Magento Documentation**: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/order-processing/rma-email-configuration.html

If you are referring to some other form of RMA functionality on a Magento 1.x Community Edition site, you'll need to determine which 3rd party module is installed to handle your RMA's, as RMA functionality is not included in Community Edition, and reach out to them for support.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using the community edition. So unless specified there's no way to know if a product return has been initiated?

Comment: I guess I would ask that you be more specific with your question. Are you referring to a customer initiated return or return initiated by a store manager in the admin?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm referring to when a customer initiate the return through the frontend.

Comment: So I ask again, what version of Magento are you using? If you are on community edition, then you have an RMA extension installed and you should contact its developer for support. RMA functionality is not included with Magento 1 Community. If you are on Enterprise, my answer suggests a solution to receive email notifications when an RMA is initiated. If that is not the type of notification that you are referring to, then you'll need to be more specific. Please keep in mind - we only know what information you provide to us.

Comment: I'm using magento 1.9 (I listed it as one of the tags). Also, I figured it out, it's the table called "rma" (lol). Basically I wrote a short mysql query inside the toolbar.phtml in magento admin view to let me know when a new row with the status "new" is added to the rma table.

Comment: So then you have a third party extension installed to handle RMA's and my answer remains the same. You should request support from the developer of the extension.

Comment: No I don't have any third party extension installed. I modified Magento view to display a message once the rma table is updated with something new.

Comment: Let me repeat - Magento 1.9 Community Edition DOES NOT include any kind of RMA functionality - this is only included in the enterprise version of Magento 1. If you have some sort of RMA functionality, and you are using Magento 1.9 Community Edition, then you have installed a third party extension to provide it to you.